# "svn log" fails after a "svn upgrade"

Tags: svn

I have a  svn working directory from about a decade ago. Using ubuntu 18.04 and svn, version 1.9.7 I tried

```
$ svn status
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: The working copy at '../from_svn_repo_arms/svn-repos'
is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.9.7 (r1800392)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

So I upgraded by doing:

```
$ svn upgrade
Upgraded '.'
Upgraded 'utils'
...

$ svn status
M       new_socket_chains/Makefile
...
...
```

Looks good, but then "svn log" fails as:

```
$ svn log
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file://<full_path>/svn-repos'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///<full_path>/svn-repos'
```

Is there and way I can recover? All I have is the directory with .svn/ under it, any SVN servers have long been lost.

Comment: "any SVN servers have long been lost". Subversion is a **centralised** version control system. If there's no repository, your history is lost. This doesn't have anything to do with working copy version.

Comment: Thanks you. Just to conclude, after some digging we  were to find a mercurial repo that was newer, and using Hg-fast-export I was able to import into git preserving all the history, etc. Work was 15-20 years old, but thankfully saved.